# Have two identical form in different page, but in one form the Post method doesn't work?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

This is first form where post method is work?

This is controller

```
@PostMapping ("/")
    public String saveCars(@ModelAttribute ("usermessage")UserMessage usermessage) {
        messagserv.saveMessage(usermessage);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
@GetMapping ("/")
public String home () {
    return "index1";
}

<div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="contact-form">
                        <form th:action="@{/}" th:object="${usermessage}" method ="post" id="add-form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="name" field="*{name}" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваше ім'я" required="required" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" name="email" field="*{email}" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваша почта" required="required" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="mobile" field="*{mobile}" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваш моб.телефон"
                                    required="required" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="message" field="*{message}"  placeholder="Суть питання"
                                    required="required"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button class="btn" id="btn" onclick="showAlert()" type="submit">Надіслати Запит</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

So when i run my application, enter field and click submit, in MySQL i can see information that i enter.

The second form in different page "/@question"

Controller

```
@GetMapping ("/questions")
    public String questions() {
        return "contact1";
    } 

@PostMapping ("/questions")
    public String question(@ModelAttribute ("usermessage") UserMessage usermessage) {
        messagserv.saveMessage(usermessage);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

And Html form

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="contact-form">
                            <form th:action="@{/}" th:object="${usermessage}" method ="post" id="add-form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="name" field="*{name}" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваше ім'я" required="required" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" name="email" field="*{email}" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваша почта" required="required" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="mobile" field="*{mobile}" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваш моб.телефон"
                                        required="required" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="message" field="*{message}"  placeholder="Суть питання"
                                        required="required"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <button class="btn" id="btn" onclick="showAlert()" type="submit">Надіслати Запит</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I can try change element th:action "@{/questions} to element "@{/} but nothing does not work. My items send, but in MySQL a can not see nothing